# Cell in react table

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I need to create a simple table in react which has three columns WO,PID,VS under which I have to give data for each of the cells. Have posted the code and also how the out put should look like check it out. I am new to react please help me out

```
class ActiveWo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tableData:[],
            
        };
    }

    render(){
const{
    tableData
}= this.state;
        const data1 = {
            "header":[
                "WO",   
                "PID",
                "VS",
            ],
    
            
            "accessorr":[
                "WO",   
                "PID",
                "VS",
            ],
            "headertext":[
                "VH"
    
            ],
            "data":[
                "10",
                "20",
                "2"
            ]
        }

        const columns = [
{
            Header:  data1 && data1.header && data1.header[0],
            accessor: data1 && data1.accessorr && data1.accessorr[0],

            Cell:(row)=>{
                return (
                    <div>
                            
  
                        {data1 && data1.header && data1.data[0]}
                        
                    </div>
                )   
            }
},
{
    Header: data1 && data1.header && data1.header[1],
    accessor: data1 && data1.accessorr && data1.accessorr[1],
    Cell:(row)=>{
        return (
            <div>
                    

                {data1 && data1.header && data1.data[1]}
                
            </div>
        )   
    }
},
{
    Header: data1 && data1.header && data1.header[2],
    accessor: data1 && data1.accessorr && data1.accessorr[2],
    Cell:(row)=>{
        return (
            <div>
                    

                {data1 && data1.header && data1.data[2]}
                
            </div>
        )   
    }
}
        ]

        const columns1 = [
            {
                        Header:  data1 && data1.header && data1.headertext[1],
                        accessor: data1 && data1.accessorr && data1.accessorr[1],
            },
            {
                Header: data1 && data1.header && data1.header[2],
                accessor: data1 && data1.accessorr && data1.accessorr[1],
            }
                    ]
        return ( 
            <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
           <TableContainer
           columns={columns}
            tableData={tableData}
             />
            </div>       
            );
}
}
export default ActiveWo;
```

Output should look like:

WO  PID VS

10  20    2

30  30    3

40  40    4

50  50    5

60  60    6

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In TableContainer component you can loop the **columns** prop for printing header and **tableData** prop to print the rows.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you should loop through the data passed from "ActiveWo" to "TableContainer". Here is one of the ways to solve your question.

*ActiveWo component:*

```
const headers = ['WO', 'PID', 'VS'];

const rows = [
  { id: 1, row: ['10', '33', '2'] },
  { id: 2, row: ['22', '11', '8'] },
  { id: 3, row: ['10', '33', '90'] },
  { id: 4, row: ['11', '22', '1'] },
  { id: 5, row: ['33', '33', '2'] },
  { id: 6, row: ['10', '23', '90'] },
];


function ActiveWo() {
  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer headers={headers} rows={rows}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default ActiveWo;
```

*TableContainer component:*

```
function TableContainer({ headers, rows }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.grid}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        {headers && headers.map((header, key) => (
          <span key={key}>
          {header}
         </span>
        ))}
      </div>
      {rows.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id} className={styles.content}>
          {item.row.map(el => (
            <span key={el.id}>
              {el}</span>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

TableContainer.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array,
};


export default TableContainer;
```

*styles for TableContainer:*

```
.grid {
 display: grid;
 width: 200px;
}

.content {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in a single component and can you please share it in javascript

Comment: @Dev, you can do it in a single component by simply moving the JSX code from TableContainer to ActiveWo.